# How to update a field if a record field of a subtable has a value?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to update Table 1, field done to yes if one of the fields of Table 2 and same idA as Table 1 has some done=yes, otherwise done=false.

I've done a Trigger to update new updates, but now I have to update all the old records I already have in the table.

**TABLE 1**

```
idA b  done
--------------
 1  a   
 2  b
 3  c
```

**TABLE 2**

```
idB idA done
--------------
 1   1   yes
 2   1   no
 3   1   yes
 4   2   no
 5   2   no
 6   3   no
 7   3   yes
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ee5f3/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN table2
ON table1.idA = table2.idA
AND table2.done = yes
SET table1.done = yes
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6066f/1